# How to force YouTube to search videos by rating?

Tags: youtube

As the title says, I want to search videos by rating. (Like whenever I hit the search bar  YouTube should sort videos by rating.)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I use chrome

Comment: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/153580 ,This script only works with one search at a time,If I search for a different word it will reset.